# Converting XML Datetime to SQL Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an XML datatype and want to convert an element into a sql DateTime variable. How?

e.g.

```
Declare @Xml Xml
Set @Xml = '<Root><DateFrom>2008-10-31T00:00:00</DateFrom></Root>'

Declare @DateFrom DateTime
Set @DateFrom = ?????
```

How can I set @DateFrom with the date from the xml above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Xml Xml
Set @Xml = '<Root><DateFrom>8/10/2008</DateFrom></Root>'

Declare @DateFrom DateTime
Select @DateFrom= t.b.value('DateFrom[1]', 'datetime')
from @xml.nodes('//Root') t(b)
```

I highly recommend you look at the `.nodes` functionality of the XML data type. The above code pulls out the value of the DateFrom element and converts it to Date Time format.